# Reading bytes from a file on SD Card - Understanding Buffer

Tags: sd-card

I have the following piece of code which opens a Bitmap from the SD card and outputs the width to the serial monitor.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File bitmap;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  bitmap = SD.open("/TEST2.BMP");

  int width[0]; // why can't I just write "int width;"
  bitmap.seek(18);
  bitmap.read(width, 4);
  Serial.println(width[0]); // and "Serial.println(width);"
}

void loop() {

}
```

It works perfectly fine but I don't understand why I have to declare the buffer for the width as `int width[0];`. I tried `int width;` but then the output is just 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't *have* to, it's just one way of doing it.

Basically the `read` function needs a pointer to a buffer to store the data in.  By using an array with one entry you get a pointer to a buffer that is big enough for one (32-bit) integer. And you then get an "easy" way of accessing that one integer within that buffer.

Another way would be to just use a simple integer and pass a pointer to that integer to `read`:

```
uint32_t width; // Use a fixed size integer for portability
bitmap.seek(18);
bitmap.read(&width, sizeof(width)); // Use sizeof for portability
Serial.println(width);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I have a bit of insight:

An array *is* a pointer. Thus,

int arr[0];

is equivalent of

int * simple;

So. read(arr...  or read(&simple...